How to set the Registry Identity using Bicep, when using Container Registry to deploy Web App in Azure?
I am having trouble setting the Registry Identity when creating an Web App using Bicep.
When I do it manually in Azure UI it works, but I want to do it with Bicep.
I thought that this section should do the trick but for some reason it is not assigning it.
Do you have any idea what is the proper syntax ?
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    httpsOnly: true
    siteConfig: {
      linuxFxVersion: 'DOTNETCORE|8.0'
      acrUseManagedIdentityCreds: true // --this is new to test the managed identity
      acrUserManagedIdentityID: managedIdentity.id
    }
  }

Here is my "full" bicep script:
var appServicePlanName = '${environmentName}-${solutionName}-plan'
var appServiceAppName = '${environmentName}-${solutionName}-app'
var sqlServerName = '${environmentName}-${solutionName}-sql'
var sqlDatabaseName = 'dis-${environmentName}'
var managedIdentityName = '${environmentName}-${solutionName}-mi'

resource managedIdentity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31' = {
  name: managedIdentityName
  location: location
}

resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2023-08-01-preview' = {
  name: sqlServerName
  location: location
  properties: {
    administratorLogin: sqlServerLogin
    administratorLoginPassword: sqlServerPassword
  }
}

resource allowAccessToAzureServices 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/firewallRules@2023-08-01-preview' = {
  parent: sqlServer
  name: 'AllowAccessToAzureServices'
  properties: {
    startIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
    endIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
  }
}

resource sqlDatabase 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2023-08-01-preview' = {
  parent: sqlServer
  name: sqlDatabaseName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: sqlDatabaseSku.name
    tier: sqlDatabaseSku.tier
  }
}

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2023-01-01' = {
  name: appServicePlanName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: appServicePlanSku.name
    tier: appServicePlanSku.tier
    capacity: appServicePlanInstanceCount
  }
  kind: 'linux'
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
}

resource appServiceApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-01-01' = {
  name: appServiceAppName
  location: location
  kind: 'app,linux,container'
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${managedIdentity.id}': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    httpsOnly: true
    siteConfig: {
      linuxFxVersion: 'DOTNETCORE|8.0'
      acrUseManagedIdentityCreds: true // --this is new to test the managed identity
      acrUserManagedIdentityID: managedIdentity.id
    }
  }
}

resource logs 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2023-01-01' = {
  name: 'logs'
  parent: appServiceApp
  properties: {
    applicationLogs: {
      fileSystem: { level: 'Verbose' }
    }
    detailedErrorMessages: { enabled: true }
    httpLogs: {
      fileSystem: { retentionInDays: 7, enabled: true }
    }
  }
}

Here is an example of manually setting the identity in the UI:


The Bicep template is specifying a runtime stack, which configures your App Service for code-based deployment:
linuxFxVersion: 'DOTNETCORE|8.0'
From your screenshot, it looks like you want to use container-based deployment instead. To do that the Bicep template would need to reference a valid image in an Azure Container Registry:
linuxFxVersion: 'DOCKER|${yourRegistryName}.azurecr.io:yourimage:latest'
To access the container image, the user-managed identity assigned to the App Service would need RBAC on the registry - likely the acrPull permission. The identity can be assigned that permission before creating the App Service.

linuxFxVersion also need been modified.
here is an example1
here is an example2
resource functionapp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-01-01' = {
  name: 'func1-${uniqueString(prefix, subscription().id)}'
  location: appLocation
  kind: 'functionapp,linux,container,azurecontainerapps'
  identity: identityInfo
  properties: {
    keyVaultReferenceIdentity: useSystemIdentity ? '': identityResourceId
    managedEnvironmentId: envId
    siteConfig: {
      linuxFxVersion: 'DOCKER|mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet8-quickstart-demo:1.0'
      acrUseManagedIdentityCreds: !useSystemIdentity
      acrUserManagedIdentityID: useSystemIdentity ? '': identityResourceId
      minimumElasticInstanceCount: 1
      functionAppScaleLimit: 5
      appSettings: appsettings
    }
  }
}

